# how to get rid of MS Azure Media Services logo overlay (water mark)

Tags: azure, media, watermark

How do you get rid of or replace the Microsoft Azure Media Services logo overlay (water mark) that is put onto dynamic packaged video? The following link shows the topic area:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/media-services-dynamic-packaging-overview/

My html contains embedded code taken from http://amsplayer.azurewebsites.net/azuremediaplayer.html

[image: Here is a screen shot...]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that you are attempting to use the iframe embed code on the "get embed code" section of the player.  Please note that this is currently under development, as it is listed on the site: "this embed code is for demo purposes only. Do not use in production."

For your player needs in production, especially if you want to use the large amounts of API's available, you should create your own player page following the instructions in the [documentation](http://aka.ms/ampdocs) and by using the [samples](http://aka.ms/ampsamples) provided.

Specifically for the question regarding the logo, there is an API available to remove to logo and can be found in the [logo option](http://aka.ms/ampdocs#amp.player.options.logo) section of the documentation. This is the correct way to remove to logo using the APIs provided.

Comment: Thanks for adding the API documentation to the logo option. My answer only fixed the symptom...not the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no documentation on how to use the logo option. 

I attempted the following:  The "enabled : false" is ignored. 
 <div id="video-viewport">
  <video id="vid1" class="azuremediaplayer amp-default-skin" autoplay  width="auto" height="540" poster="" data-setup='{"nativeControlsForTouch": false}, "techOrder": ["azureHtml5JS", "flashSS", "silverlightSS", "html5"], "logo": { enabled: false}' >

Comment: @user908998 I think you are putting this in the incorrect location and incorrectly closing brackets.  

<video id="azuremediaplayer" class="azuremediaplayer amp-default-skin amp-big-play-centered" controls autoplay width="640" height="400" data-setup='{"logo": {"enabled": false}}' tabindex="0">  

Check out the options in the documentation for details http://aka.ms/ampdocs#options. The are different ways to initializing with options depending if you are using the <video> statically or if using JavaScript dynamically.  Samples for both approaches can be found http://aka.ms/ampsamples

Answer (score 3):

It might be helpful to post some of the HTML that you are using  when you say "My html contains embedded code taken from..."

It looks like the code on that page has the following div:

```
<div class="amp-logo" style="opacity: 0.5;"></div>
```

This appears to be what is placing the logo on the page you reference. Not know what HTML is actually in your page, I don't know if this is the HTML they are generating for you as embedded or whether you cut and paste the HTML from the given page.

You may be able to remove it from your HTML. If not, try creating a style that overrides the amp-logo class.

Comment: Thanks Brian. That was it.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Consider marking the question as answered so it correctly filters out.